# Python Operator Overloading

Tags: python, operators, overloading, typeerror

I have a problem with overloading adding operator in Python.
Everytime I try to overload it i get:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Car:
    carCount = 0

    def __init__(self,brand,cost):
        self.brand = brand
        self.cost = cost
        Car.carCount +=1
    def displayCount(self):
        print "Number of cars: %d" % Car.carCount
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Brand: %r   Cost: %d' % (self.brand, self.cost)
    def __del__(self):
        class_name = self.__class__.__name__
        print class_name,'destroyed'
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Car(self.cost+other.cost)


c=Car("Honda",10000)
d=Car("BMW",20000)
print c
a= c+d
```

Comment: `return Car(self.cost+other.cost)`. you are missing brand but I imagine you want   `return self.cost+other.cost`

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to add cars like that; a car plus a car isn't also a car!

Comment: When you add two cars together, what's the resulting `brand`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `__init__` takes three arguments (including `self`) and you have supplied just two in your `__add__` method, hence the `TypeError` for `__init__`:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

So in your `__add__` you should add (no pun intended) the `brand` argument:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Car(self.brand+other.brand, self.cost+other.cost)
```

So you'll get a `"Honda BMW"` in this case which probably isn't what you want.

Either way, I'm sure you understand the error now and you'll fix it to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the `__add__` method, you should pass two arguments; `brand` is missing:

```
def __add__(self,other):
    return Car('', self.cost+other.cost)
    #          ^^
```